# No Event Handler Window in Visual Studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I just wanted to know :

When i Code in WPF C# i have a small Button for events of GUI Elements
in the Propertie Window and i can just double Click it so it generates an event.

Something like:

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlmci.png ( The Flash Icon in the Top Right Corner)

If i create a Xamarin Android Project in Visual Studio C# i just get a properties Window. No Nice and Fast Auto Event Generation :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKOv7.png ( Just the Properties)

Question: Does the Actions Window simply doesnt exist in Xamarin Visual Studio 
C# . (I think  on Xamarin IOS you can do it).
Can Visual Studio auto generate Event handler for Xamarin in some way, or must i code every single one of them by Hand?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question: Does the Actions Window simply doesnt exist in Xamarin Visual Studio C# . (I think on Xamarin IOS you can do it). Can Visual Studio auto generate Event handler for Xamarin in some way, or must i code every single one of them by Hand?

Currently VS can't generate Event Handler in Xamarin Designer. Personally I also had pains in coding event handlers. But then I found a way to quickly generate the event handler in the Editor that might be helpful:

1. In `OnCreate` Method of your Activity find the target element:

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);
       SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

       var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClick);
   }
   ```
2. code `button.Click+=` then press `tab` on the keyboard:

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);
       SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

       var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClick);
       button.Click+= //press 'tab' now
   }
   ```
3. VS will generate the event handler then:

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
       base.OnCreate(bundle);
       SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

       var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClick);
       button.Click += Button_Click;
   }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       throw new System.NotImplementedException();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this Tip !
(Its less painfully now :D
I hope Microsoft will add this feature some day in Visual Studio